# Concatenate strings sometimes in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a dataframe containing made up sentences.
In order to make the sentences vary I want to sometimes concatenate a string to a pre-existing string and sometimes not

**Example input**

```
FD1<-data.frame(c("It is raining","It is snowing","It is stormy"))
FD_try<-list(x="a lot",x="a bit")


It is raining
It is snowing
It is stormy
```

**Example output 1**

```
It is raining a lot
It is snowing
It is stormy
```

**Example output 1**

```
It is raining 
It is snowing a lot
It is stormy a bit
```

I am currently doing

```
out <- apply(FD1, 1, function(x) {

    return(paste(x,sample(FD_try,1,replace=F)))
  })
```

but that always inserts from FD_try. How can I make it insert only sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
FD1 <- data.frame(x=c("It is raining", "It is snowing", "It is stormy"))
FD_try <- c("a lot", "a bit", "")
FD1$new <- paste0(FD1$x, sample(FD_try, nrow(FD1), repl=TRUE))
FD1
```

You can use `replace=FALSE` only if `nrow(FD1)<=length(FD_try)`

Comment: so the replace =T makes it optional. Got it.

Comment: If you want to use `replace=FALSE`, there must `nrow(FD1)<=length(FD_try)`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this helps

```
trimws(paste(FD1[,1], c("", unlist(FD_try))))
```

Comment: ...One of those 'why didn't I think of that' moments

Comment: ...but if there also a way of sampling so that if I wanted I could optionally add two of the elements in FD_try to get for example It is raining a lot a bit

Comment: @SebastianZeki  You can concatenate in that list and do a `sample` on it